# Why does document.images contain more than just image references?

Tags: javascript, dom, domdocument

JavaScript newbie here, gentleness requested. The JavaScript resources I'm using all seem to say that `document.images` is an array (update: except it's not an array; see Badacadabra's answer below) of references to `img` elements on a page. That's clear enough, so to drill it in, I wrote **[this](https://codepen.io/globewalldesk/pen/VbXxQQ)**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <img src="http://java2s.com/style/demo/border.png" width="150" height="113">
  <img src="http://java2s.com/style/demo/border.png" width="150" height="113">       
  <img src="http://java2s.com/style/demo/border.png" width="150" height="113">
  <p><button onclick="myFunction()">test</button></p>
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      image_report = ""
      for (i in document.images) {
        image_report = image_report + document.images[i].src + "<br>";
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = image_report;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But rather than getting just a list of `src` values for the page's three images, I also get three more objects for which `src` is undefined:

```
http://java2s.com/style/demo/border.png
http://java2s.com/style/demo/border.png
http://java2s.com/style/demo/border.png
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

What are those and what are they doing there? And why isn't this explained, e.g., **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/images)**? Am I maybe missing something about how `for...in` works?

Comment: _"Am I maybe missing something about how `for...in` works?"_ `document.images["length"].src`, `document.images["item"].src`, `document.images["namedItem"].src` are `undefined`. You can verify this by including `console.log(i)` within `for..in` loop.

Answer (score 2):

> The `for...in` statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an
>   object

[`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) is also getting `.length`, `.item` and `.namedItem` properties of `document.images`

You can alternatively use `for..of` loop

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <img src="http://java2s.com/style/demo/border.png" width="150" height="113">
  <img src="http://java2s.com/style/demo/border.png" width="150" height="113">       
  <img src="http://java2s.com/style/demo/border.png" width="150" height="113">
  <p><button onclick="myFunction()">test</button></p>
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      image_report = ""
      for (let image of document.images) {
        image_report = image_report + image.src + "<br>";
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = image_report;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this instead:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img')
```

Comment: Useful, and I did come across that in my research, but I'm still curious what those three objects appended at the end are doing there...

Answer (score 1):

`document.images` is **NOT** an array.

```js
console.log(Array.isArray(document.images));
```

`document.images` is an **HTMLCollection**, which is an **array-like object**. An array-like object looks like an array (keys are numbers), has a length property, but is not an instance of `Array` and does not have access to `Array.prototype` methods.

This code should work, by the way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
  console.log(document.images[i].src);
}
```